# Why we do not specify parameters in Elm function composition?

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I was looking at various examples of function compositions and all of them have type definition stating the input and output parameters. On the other hand the function definition does not pass parameters. Is it because all the functions have same type signature? All the examples I have seen are

> fn: String -> String

can you compose a function with more than one parameter passed?

Comment: "*function definition does not pass parameters*" - wat? Can you give an example of code you are referring to?

Comment: You'll want to take a look at https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elm function type definitions work like this:

```
myFunction : FirstArg -> SecondArg -> ... -> LastArg -> ReturnType
```

Examples:

```
-- one argument
sqrt : Float -> Float

-- two arguments
rem : Int -> Int -> Int

-- no arguments (constant!)
pi : Float
```

The composition function has this type signature:

```
(>>) : (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c
```

Which, if you add parentheses, can be thought of as

```
(>>) : (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> c)
```

Thus, it needs two functions of one argument and returns another function of one argument.

**If you wanted to use it with functions taking more arguments, you'd have to partially apply them, to make them only need one argument:**

```
((+) 5) >> ((*) 2)
-- (+) needs two arguments
-- (+) 5 needs one argument
-- same with (*) and (*) 2
-- the above line is the same as
\num -> 2 * (5 + num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, I don't know Elm, but I think I can answer this in a general way.

Say you have a function:

```
function addTwo(n) {
    return n + 2;
}
```

And say you want to give the function another name for whatever reason. You could write:

```
function otherName(n) {
    return addTwo(n);
}
```

You specify the parameter of `otherName`, then manually pass it to `addTwo`.

But wait, if all you're doing is passing the parameter straight to the inner function, is it necessary to specify the parameter at all? Why not just write:

```
otherName = addTwo
```

How does this relate to the question? Pretend `addTwo` is a composition. It takes a number, and returns a number. Like in the second example, you could be explicit and write the parameter out, but it's not necessary. Really, all you're doing when you assign a composition to a variable is giving the composed function a name. The parameters have nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function with multiple arguments in elm, to do so you need to use (from) two arrows in your function signature type definition:

```
divide: Float -> Float -> String
divide x y =
  x / y |> toString
```

So: type of the first argument, then type of the second argument and then the type of the return value.

More details in the [elm-guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/reading_types.html#named-functions)